# Fullcalendar v2 store dragged event into localstorage

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

How can I store my dragged events into localstorage ? I have figured out in old fullcalendar version but this solution is not working any more.

```
var EventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: document.getElementById("content"),
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
    var events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events'));
    var events = new Events(events);
    var jsevents = events.toJSON();
    this.el.innerHTML = _.template( calendarTemplate,{data : jsevents} );
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        agenda: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}',
                    '': 'h(:mm)t',
            aspectRatio: 1.5,
            droppable: true,
            weekend: true,
            editable: true,
            eventDrop: function(event) {

                // ???????????????????????????????

            },
            defaultView: 'month',
            firstDay: 1,
            handleWindowResize: true,
            allDayDefault: false,
            firstHour: 7,
            columnFormat: {
                month: 'dddd',    
                week: 'ddd, dS', 
                day: 'dddd, MMM dS'
            },
            header: {
                right: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
             var title = prompt('Event Title:');
             var eventData;
             if (title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end
            };
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
            events.push(eventData);
            localStorage.setItem('events',JSON.stringify(events));
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
         },
             events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                callback(jsevents);
            }
        });
    },
```

You can see my select function fully working. I mean selected events are stored into database.

Answer (score 2):

i was able to replicate your example, and it worked just fine, the only thing i added is the definition of Events, i made it as backbone collection

```
var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```

I think you need to debug while setting the value in local storage, try to log the value of

```
JSON.stringify(events)
```

just before setting in local storage

EDIT:
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mfarouk/vcsr45q8/25/